# strapi & graphql : how to get total count of items?

Tags: graphql, strapi, nuxt-strapi

I'm using **strapi** and **graphQL** ,

with this query i can get posts

```
query {
  
  posts{
    id,
    title
  }
}
```

i want to get **posts** and **totalCount** **together** ,desirable result would like this

```
{
  "data": {

"totalCount" : "3",
    "posts": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "first post "
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "post two"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "post 3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've read **document** and I can make a query for getting **just total count** but it is not enough for me !
so , How can i get **posts** and **totalCounts** together ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found myself in your shoes right now and the solution I found was:

```
    query POSTS {
      postsConnection {
        aggregate {
          count
        }
      }
      posts{
        id
        title
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a similar way to do it through the REST API?